# WCF windows service with UI (Server side) + Client Side UI

Tags: wpf, wcf, windows-services, client-server

I am making an application which will be a client/server (Both WPF) at the server side i wish to make a WCF (Windows Service) which will communicate with the client side

But i want that some settings of my WCF service is configurable (paths,ports,credentials bindings etc..) this is where server side GUI comes in picture.

How to make a Presenration Layer of server side configure a windows service (Including WCF specific attributes)

Comment: A service typically doesn't have an UI. I would recommend to (a) either use just your favorite text editor to edit the service's `.config` file, or (b) create a separate Config UI for handling that task. Don't stick this stuff into the service itself.

Comment: @marc_s I didnt get the (b) part exactly. I have seen apps (like sound control panel (srs Audio)) which have a UI and also change use a winodws service ... do they use the same (b) approach ??

Comment: If you need to be able to set the config values from a UI - create a separate Config tool to read the config values, present them on a UI, and save them back to the config file. Key part: *separate* config tool - don't code this inside your Windows service.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) . So what i understood is I should create a config file in a seperate location (May be in %appdata%) so that My service can read it and my UI can read it and write it.

Comment: The config file needs to be where the service is - don't mess with that. Just put the code to modify that via an UI into a separate utility app.